# Some event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I would like make simple app that user can draw a circle and resize and drag it
and at the end receive center position and distance.
I made it and it works fine but when the circle is dragged or resized, events not trigger.

This is my code, note that `overlaycomplete` and `circlecomplete` work.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        drawingControl: false,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
            ]
        },
        circleOptions: {
            fillColor: '#000000',
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        var coordinates = (e);
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (e) {
        var coordinates = (e);
        console.log(coordinates);
        console.log('radius', coordinates.getRadius());
        console.log(coordinates.getCenter().lat())
        console.log(coordinates.getCenter().lng())
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'center_changed', function (e) {
        var coordinates = (e);
        console.log(coordinates);
        console.log('radius', coordinates.getRadius());
        console.log(coordinates.getCenter().lat())
        console.log(coordinates.getCenter().lng())
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'distance_changed', function (e) {
        var coordinates = (e);
        console.log(coordinates);
        console.log('radius', coordinates.getRadius());
        console.log(coordinates.getCenter().lat())
        console.log(coordinates.getCenter().lng())
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `center_changed` and `distance_changed` are not events dispatched by the [DrawingManager Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager)

There is a `center_changed` event dispatched by the [Map class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map), but this event is triggered when the center of the map is changed, not the center of a circle overlay.

**Edit: (untested)**

You have to use the [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Circle) overlay instance events such `radius_changed`, `drag` or `dragend`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
    console.log('radius at creation', circle.getRadius());
    console.log('lat at creation', circle.getCenter().lat())
    console.log('lon at creation', circle.getCenter().lng())
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function () {
        console.log('radius after change', circle.getRadius());
        console.log('lat after radius change', circle.getCenter().lat())
        console.log('lon after radius change', circle.getCenter().lng())
     });
    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'dragend', function () {
        console.log('radius at dragend', circle.getRadius());
        console.log('lat at dragend', circle.getCenter().lat())
        console.log('lon at dragend', circle.getCenter().lng())
     });
});
```

Comment: tnx 'radius_changed' and 'center_changed' works like charm but why mouseup event doesn't work? this is my code     google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mouseup', function (event) {
      alert('test');
    });

Comment: could be that your browser blocks alert(), if not can you create a jsfiddle that reproduce?

Comment: I am sorry you jsfiddle seems to be empty